# Can I make purple watercolor paint from boiling Scottish thistle flowers?

Tags: painting, paint, watercolor

### Can you make purple watercolor paint by boiling purple-colored thistle flowers?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

No, if you boil thistle flowers at 212°F, the resulting solution will turn light brown.

It makes okay light brown water-color paint

Comment: Have you tried extracting without the boiling?